# How to use EasyRec in my webPage

Tags: java, resteasy

I am very new to this EasyRec recommendation Application. I deployed Easyrec war file in my System and login with my credentails, i created my own telnet with product url, now i want to add product ids in Easyrec as items ids, but i am far away of "how to use easyrec"
1)How to add item details in easyrec
2) where i need to add details in Easyrec

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same problem. How you send item details to easyrec ??

Answer (score 1):

you should use the API of easyrec - they released a great tool to playaround with your API few days ago ... http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/APITEST.html

you should read the wiki pages which cover the basics of the easyrec recommender system...
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/easyrec/index.php?title=Documentation_v0.97

to get started you could use the Javascript API which is very easy to use...
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/easyrec/index.php?title=JavaScript_API_v0.97

Comment: I am not getting any point how to use easyrec in my grails app